# How to tell where the database schema and mapping is not in sync?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I run the following command and see that the mapping and schema are not in sync.  Is there some way to see where it is out of sync?  Note that I thought that using the verbose flag `-v`, `-vv`, or `-vvv` flag would show this but either I am doing it wrong or it doesn't work as none of these flags change the output.

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema -vvv
Mapping
-------
 [OK] The mapping files are correct.
Database
--------
 [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump differences:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

Apply them:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

Comment: Thanks.  Ended up just changing the schema so I can't verify this time but will do next time.

Comment: Sure, you can test this easily by introducing any change to an underlying table.

Comment: Yes, works great.  Do you know if the verbose flags don't work or is it just me?

Comment: The verbose flag is a standard Symfony console flag, it's up to the programmer to use it or not. I'm pretty sure it does nothing special in the schema tool. I encourage you not to use the schema tool though and switch to migrations. It's much safer if you plan to move to production / work with larger dev team, etc. Changes can be documented too, the schema tool is fine for the development only.